# Is it possible to use more than 20 layers?

Tags: render-layers, layers

Is it possible to use more than 20 Scene layers or Render layers in Blender?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. A `Scene` object only contains [exactly](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.layers)  20 layers, no more, no less. But if you mean render layers, the upper limit is [32768](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.RenderLayers.html#bpy.types.RenderLayers.active_index).

Answer (score 4):

While the 3DView is fixed at 20 layers, you can get similar functionality using groups. By having the outliner list groups you can show/hide all objects in a group at the one time. This method hides objects, so is basically a shortcut to hide/unhide multiple objects without having to manually select each one.

The catch with groups is that while an object on a visible layer is always visible even if a second layer it is on is hidden, using groups means all objects in a group get hidden even if they are in another group that you want to stay visible. You also don't get easy keyboard shortcuts to hide a group.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, Blender is limited to 20 layers (this may change with version 2.8). There are two useful addons that try to bypass this limit: **Super Grouper** and **Objects Layer Manager**

**[Objects Layer Manager](https://www.blendernation.com/2015/10/28/add-on-objects-library-manager)** is very similar to using groups, as described by @sambler above. The issue is that if you would like to temporarily hide some objects, when you unhide them, it resets the visibility of the layers within the addon.

[image]

**[Super Grouper](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360257-Super-Grouper)**, on the other hand does not simply hide and unhide objects, but temporarily moves hidden objects to a different scene, meaning that the layer system provided by the addon does not interfere with any hidden or visible objects within the current scene.

[image][image]