# How to move objects to new Render Layer?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, scene, render-layers

This question has been asked several times before, but one thing is not clear.

There are *Render layers*. Each *Render layer* itself seems to have *Scene* and *Layer* slots. It's not clear what each is. Pressing <kbd>M</kbd> and choosing the slot seems to move the object to a new *Scene* slot of the current *Render layer* of the object. Is that right?

It doesn't seem to move the object to another *Render layer*. How is the latter done?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32885/599

Comment: M doesn't appear to do what the gif in that topic suggests (move object ot another "Render layer").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way this works is indeed quite confusing.

**TL;DR:** <kbd>M</kbd> moves objects between *layers*, which are independent of the many *layer visibility* settings.

---

**Long answer:**

There are 20 *layers* and several independent places where they can be visible or hidden:

## Scene layer visibility

[image]

These are the layers which are visible in all 3D views with *Lock Camera and Layers* enabled in *3D view > Header*:

[image]

Changing the visible layers in any 3D view will change the scene layer visibility and thereby change the layer visibility of any other 3D views with *Lock Camera and Layers* enabled.

[image]

*Note that despite being in the renderlayers panel, this setting is global per scene and not unique between renderlayers.*

## Viewport layer visibility

[image]

These are the layers visible in that particular 3D view. If *Lock Camera and Layers* is disabled, this can be set independently of the scene layer visibility.

[image]

### Render layers

[image]

Unlike *layers*, [of which there are always 20](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2836/599), you can have an arbitrary number of renderlayers.

A [*Renderlayer*](http://blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html) contains a *layer* visibility selection which specifies which *layers* are visible in that particular renderlayer:

[image]

Note that **only objects in the active 3D view's visible layers will be rendered**. In case of multiple 3D views, the *active* 3D view is the one under the mouse cursor.

This means that the behavior of the final render can *depend on mouse position*.

This also means that if all your 3D views have *Lock Camera and Layers* disabled, the *Scene* layer visibility doesn't do anything.

<sub>This wasn't always the case. [In 2.69 scene layer visibility was used instead of viewport layer visibility, which IMO makes a *lot* more sense..](https://developer.blender.org/T45162)</sub>

Comment: Wow, confusing indeed, I might have to reread it few times before I understand everything.