# Cycles render won't render one object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv

I have my lightsaber object and the textures on it, which render perfectly. I also have the plane underneath it that just renders out black. I think it may have to do with me possibly messing up the UV mapping of the plane.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39686/1853

Answer (score 2):

Right now your ground plane is set to a layer that has not been set to render.

Move the ground plane that remains black to a layer thats beïng rendered like Layer 1. (Select the plane, press M, and select the first box)

[image]

Or enable the layer which contains the ground plane in your scene settings. (shift + LMB on the box/layer which contains the ground plane)

[image]

Hope this works for you...

B.t.w. The smoke texture from the other plane is missing. You can pack this in your blendfile using File > External Data > Pack all into blendfile or auto pack.