# Blender cycles CUDA out of memory error in archviz scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have made an arcviz scene with different objects that are complex (level of detail pretty good and I prepared render but there is a problem: the cuda memory (3 gb) is not enough for the scene. I am trying to solve the thing without actually losing precision or realism, but the problem still persist (I tried rendering layers separated but there is still the problem of the objects being connected  (shadows or others) one another, so if i render one, it seems out of place because it hsn't the shadow or reflexed of other objects of the scene. Do you have any suggestion? [image]

[image]

Comment: If rendered on different render layers and composited properly there shouldn't be any problems or visible seams. It could help if you show how do you composite render layers. Also most likely putting object with particle system on another render layer could be enough to minimize VRAM usage

Comment: If you're lighting it with an hdri you could opt for a lower resolution one, that helps me sometimes. Nice scene btw!

Comment: Does using a lower tile size help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the rug is causing the problem, due to the number of hair particles. If that is the cause, try changing the particle settings or use geometry instead of the hair strands as strand.

Or invest in a better graphics cards, Gtx 1060 with 6 gig of memory works great for my projects.

Comment: While investing into a "better" GPU might solve some problems, you sooner or later will run into that problem again, anyway - if you're going to move to more complex scenes, that is. (My Radeon Pro with 16GB also works great, it's just not an option for everyone).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to complex scenes with particle systems, you might invest some time into learning compositing.

You can separate your scene's problematic elements into Render Layers, render them individually and then using Blender's built-in compositor to "glue" the layers back together.

For a quick explanation on how to use the various layers in Blender, check out Gandalf's explanation here:

[How to move objects to new Render Layer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39681/how-to-move-objects-to-new-render-layer)

Blenderguru has a good tutorial about splitting up a scene for rendering and then using the compositor to combine them again, which you can find here:

https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing